# Why does Apache Flink stall in method org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.Serializers.getContainedGenericTypes?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, kryo

While implementing my algorithm I have created a long chain of operators in Apache Flink with for loop. Starting from some length processing stalls in method 
org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.Serializers.getContainedGenericTypes for a long time before actual processing. How can be explained this phenomenon? How can it be addressed in order to reduce this method time?

[image]

Comment: What data types are you using in your stream? Potentially, your Kryo types are not registered.

Comment: I am using case class types with the primitives inside, like case class Cell (i:Int.j:Int,v1:Int,v2:Int). I'm exploting system for batch processing of DataSet[Cell].

Comment: @rmetzger Should I register these types explicitly somehow?

Comment: No, you don't need to register the type. That's what the `Serializers` class is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Serializers.getContainedGenericTypes()` method is only called during the plan creation of your `DataSet` application.

Setting `ExecutionConfig.disableAutoTypeRegistration()` will disable this registration.

I assume you are running your Flink application locally without a lot of data. Usually, the plan creation takes only a small fraction of the available CPU time, and the actual processing eats up most of it.

Comment: Yes, the assumption is true. Flink should process several megabytes in this run. I hope to process several terabytes on cluster in my research. After disabling of the automatic type registration I have a similar trouble. I am getting `org.apache.flink.optimizer.traversals` ~50%, `org.apache.flink.optimizer.plan` ~32%, `java.util` ~17% of CPU time in profiler and no response for several hours.

Comment: For processing several megabytes, you don't need a big distributed processing framework. Java collections will do the job.
Once you are going to process several terabytes, the optimizer or type registration will not dominate the costs anymore.

Comment: The problem is that it hangs. Graph is not starting. It is not a simple overhead. I want to run an algorithm that generates 6 layers. In this I have tried to show the complexity of the graph https://gist.github.com/protsenkovi/3f0cba82978c8ea41bd191cd9a1b1714.